# Knockout Nested Object Scoping Undefined Reference

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, scope

I'm trying to write a basic form using KnockoutJS using the following code:

```
var Form = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = {
        value: ko.observable(""),
        isValid: ko.computed(function () {
            return self.name.value().length > 0;
        }),
    },
    self.email = {
        value: ko.observable(""),
        isValid: ko.computed(function () {
            return false;
        })
    },
    self.message = {
        value: ko.observable(""),
        isValid: ko.computed(function () {
            return false;
        })
    },
    self.isValid = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.name.isValid && self.email.isValid && self.message.isValid;
    })
};
```

However, when I try to run this code I get the following error: `Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference`. To me, this looks like a scope issue, but I'm not familiar enough with Knockout to understand why this is happening. Without Knockout I seem to be able to get this code working (replacing all observables with true for value and functions for isValid), but I'm looking to get these values updated in real-time. I *could* always separate out the validation functions to top-level functions but it seems like the improper way to do this. Each form field has a value and it's own unique validation, so it makes sense to make each form field it's own object with both properties.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
self.name = {
    value: ko.observable(""),
    isValid: ko.computed(function () {
        return self.name.value().length > 0;
    }),
},
```

doesn't work because the inner function (the computed callback) refers to `self.name`, which is not even completely defined yet. Since computeds are called immediately, you see an error.

You *could* use the [`deferEvaluation` option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#constructing-a-computed-observable) to delay evaluating the `isValid` computed until something actually requests its value:

```
self.name = {
    value: ko.observable(""),
    isValid: ko.computed({
        read: function () { return self.name.value().length > 0; },
        deferEvaluation: true
    }),
},
```

That would work, but it would also quickly start to become repetitive and unwieldy.

---

As an alternative you can use Knockout [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) to make an observable validatatable in an abstract/decoupled fashion.

```
ko.extenders.validator = function (target, validationCallback) {
    // create an isValid property on the target observable, 
    // immediately calculate validity of its current value
    target.isValid = ko.observable(validationCallback(target()));

    // subscribe to future changes
    target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        target.isValid(validationCallback(newValue));
    });

    // return target observable for chaining
    return target;
};
```

Now with this extender defined, all you need to do is create callback functions that validate a value and return true or false.

```
var Form = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable("").extend({
        validator: function (value) { return value.length > 0; }
    });
    self.email = ko.observable("").extend({
        validator: function (value) { return true; }
    });
    self.message = ko.observable("").extend({
        validator: function (value) { return true; }
    });
    self.isValid = ko.computed(function () {
        var overallValid = true;
        ko.utils.objectForEach(self, function (key, value) {
            if (value.hasOwnProperty("isValid")) {
                overallValid = overallValid && value.isValid();
            }
        });
        return overallValid;
    });
};
```

Further separating your validation functions now becomes very simple:

```
var validators = {
    email: function (value) { return /* email check here */; },
    minLen: function (minLen) {
        return function (value) { return value.length >= minLen; }
    },
    maxLen: function (maxLen) {
        return function (value) { return value.length <= maxLen; }
    },
    minmaxLen: function (minLen, maxLen) {
        return function (value) { return value.length >= minLen && value.length <= maxLen; }
    },
    matches: function (regex) {
        return function (value) { return regex.test(value); }
    }
}
```

and

```
self.name = ko.observable("").extend({ validator: validators.minLen(1) });
self.age = ko.observable("").extend({ validator: validators.matches(/^\d+$/) });
```

---

You will find that of course [somebody already did all of this](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) (and much more).

Comment: Excellent explanation and answer, wish I could give you more points. I went with the `deferEvaluation` option because it's a dinky contact form, the only form on the entire site. I do appreciate the elaboration on extending the objects and if this project was bigger than a one-page personal site I would surely have done it that way to decouple the code and make it easier to read. I also don't want to include another library (Knockout Validation) since I'm really just checking valid email and non-empty fields, but again, thanks for the excellent answer.

Comment: Fair enough, using the simplest thing that works is not a bad approach.

Comment: Jeez if that doesn't make me feel guilty/lazy :-P

Comment: No, that was a completely sincere statement, corollary of YAGNI. I consider it an actual ability if someone can assess a situation and resist the urge to overengineer without doing the Wrong Thing -and `deferEvaluation` definitely isn't the Wrong Thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to create separate functions for each of your objects:

```
var Form = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.name = new NameFormField();
}

var NameFormField = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.value = ko.observable("");
    self.isValid = ko.computed(function () {
        //not sure why you are checking length here
        return self.value().length > 0;
    });
}
```

The other way that you could get it to work is by doing this:

```
var Form = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.name = {
        value: ko.observable("")
    };

    self.name.isValid = ko.computed(function () {
        //not sure why you are checking length here
        return self.name.value().length > 0;
    });
```